# Where is require('cookieParser') present in express 3?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a node js application and trying to use cookieParser in the below way:-

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.cookieParser());
```

I can find cookieParser.js which is present in the connect. I can also see that we are exporting this cookieParser function in cookieParser.js. However I am unable to find the place where we are using require('ccokieParser') in express or connect, even though I can use cookieParser by calling express.cookieParser()

Answer (score 1):

hope this example will help you..

```
var express      = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Cookies: ", req.cookies)
})

app.listen(8080)
```

Comment: Hi donno1, I understand how to use  cookieParser. My question is in which js in the connect/express module have we imported the cookieParser module?

Comment: hope this link will help you..http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieParser.html

Comment: It does'nt help. I am asking the file in connect module where require('cookieParser') is written?

Comment: according my example it is written on line 2 plz see

Comment: It does'nt help. I am asking something different.

Comment: What I am trying to ask is in which file in connect require('cookie-parser') is written? Where is this module imported in connect, in which javascript file?